# SQL query for insert into with update on duplicate key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `debitTable` and `creditTable`.

`debitTable` has the following records:

```
+----+-------+
| id | debit |
+----+-------+
| a  | 10000 |
| b  | 35000 |
+----+-------+
```

and `creditTable` has these records:

```
+----+--------+
| id | credit |
+----+--------+
| b  | 5000   |
+----+--------+
```

How about the SQL Server query to produce these results:

```
+----+----------------+--------------+
| id | debit | credit | debit-credit |
+----+----------------+--------------+
| a  | 10000 |   0    |     10000    |
| b  | 35000 |  5000  |     30000    |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a `join`.  However, it is important to aggregate before joining:

```
select coalesce(d.id, c.id) as id, coalesce(credit, 0) as credit,
       (coalesce(debit, 0) - coalesce(credit, 0)) as DebitMinusCredit
from (select id, sum(debit) as debit
      from debit
      group by id
     ) d full outer join
     (select id, sum(credit) as credit
      from debit
      group by id
     ) c
     on d.id = c.id;
```

This uses `full outer join` to ensure that all records from both tables are included, even if an id is not in one of the tables.  The aggregation before joining is to avoid Cartesian products when there are multiple rows for a single id in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "Left Join"

```
Select * 
from debit d 
left join credit c on d.id = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    debit.id, debit.debit, credit.credit, 
    debit.debit - credit.credit as [debit-credit]
from 
    debit 
left join 
    credit on debit.id = credit.id
```

BUT this will be based only on debit: meaning if you have id in credit which is not in debit it won't appear in this result.